# How to output my recorded audio file in my laptop?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

`mFilename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`
`mFilename += "/audiorecorder.3gp";`
`mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();`
`mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);`
`mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);`
`mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);`
`mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFilename);`
`mRecorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListenerForRecorder);`

Above is my settings for MediaRecord. I can record sound from microphone into .3pg audio file perfectly. I simulated it on Android AVD and I can only find the output file in SD card. But I hope I can also output my audio file on my computer. It is also strange that I can not find the output file in my computer when I was running AVD. So where the audio file is stored when I was running AVD? Could anyone tell me how to set the output path? THX!

Answer (score 1):

Well here is your solution. You can't refer to any drive location of your harddisk to android. Android will consider only the path associated to either external memory or internal phone memory.

And as for your question where the output will be stored when you use an AVD is also simple. You can view the SD card details in File Explorer. To get the file explorer in eclipse **window->Show view->File Explorer**

Comment: Then, Can I get the file out from the AVD SDcard to my computer?

Comment: yeah u can push and pull files to sdcard. u can see an icon in the top right corner in file explorer of eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I got it just now.